# WebStorm - JSX formatting, break line before custom components

Tags: webstorm, jsx

Consider the following:

```
<MuiThemeProvider
            muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}><Button>Stuff!</Button><MyComponent><AnotherComponent>Content</AnotherComponent>
</MuiThemeProvider>);
```

For whatever reason, all components defined are treated as inlines, which means WebStorm's formatting doesn't break lines & indent them by default.

Specifying the component name in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other | Insert new line before** doesn't do a thing.

Please tell me how to make WebStorm insert a newline and indent properly all custom JSX components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add line breaks manually and ensure that **Keep line breaks in text** is enabled in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML, Other**.

Please check/vote for [WEB-37966](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37966)